# Creating a constant Expression in C#

Tags: c#, lambda, expression, expression-trees

Is there a way to create an expression in C#, that returns a constant value, but also has a parameter?

Using code, it would look like

```
var expression = x => 5
```

So it should match `Expression<Func<double, double>>` type.

It probably should look like

```
ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(double), "parameter");
ConstantExpression constant = Expression.Constant(0.0);
var expression = Expression.SomeMagic(param, constant);
Expression.Lambda<Func<double, double>>(expression);
```

Comment: What magic are you expecting to need to do?  You have the parameter, you have the body of the lambda, you know how to put the two things together, what more do you need?

Comment: Why not return a hardcoded lambda (maybe in a closure so you could parameterize it?)

Comment: Expression class has a few methods to combine other expressions, I just can't figure out, what method I should use to get `x => 5`, not `() => 5`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass your parameters into Expression.Lambda<>() :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268052(v=vs.110).aspx

So you're looking for something like :

```
ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(double), "parameter");
ConstantExpression constant = Expression.Constant(0.0);

var expression = // build the body ...


Expression.Lambda<Func<double, double>>(expression, param);
```

To return the same parameter, it'd be as simple as :

```
ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(double), "parameter");

Expression.Lambda<Func<double, double>>(param, param);
```

To return the constant value would be :

```
ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(double), "parameter");
ConstantExpression constant = Expression.Constant(0.0);

Expression.Lambda<Func<double, double>>(constant, param);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "parameter");
var f = Expression.Lambda<Func<string, string>>(param, param).Compile();
```

```
const string c = "Name";
if (object.ReferenceEquals(c, f("Name")) {
  // It's a constant
}
```